# Xcode 6 view controller showing blank screen with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to use view controller that I decided to use auto layout for. Before I used auto layout, the view showed normally like how I intended it to during runtime. But I decided to switch to auto layout (because after all, bigger iPhones are coming), and even after setting it up, getting no issues at all, and seeing that the app scaled well to the iPhone size in IB; I still have a blank screen. To prove it, here are pictures:

[image: Xcode 6 shot.[][1]]

[image: iOS Simulator shot. Note that the navigation bar and tab bars are showing.]

So why is this happening? I added the constraints in the square view, and it gracefully scaled to the iPhone view in Interface Builder. If you also look at the sidebar, the alerts for auto layout errors are not present. And IB is rendering everything. But why is the simulator blank?

And yes, I connected all the elements to be code correctly. I verified. And yes, I have code that puts text in a label. Here it is, in the 'viewDidLoad()' method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.titleLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
}
```

And I will reemphasise: the app worked before I did auto layout. For this build, I deleted all the elements, relocated them, reconnected them, and added tweaked the view with auto layout unit IB rendered it correctly. But I'm getting different results here.

Please help me. Oh, and sorry for the massive images, I can't figure out how to shrink them.

EDIT: I've gone through and used the view debugger, and tried to capture the view hierarchy to look for clipping or occlusion. Funny enough, the view debugger shows the content properly, and there wasn't any clipping or occlusion that I saw. When I tried to show frames in the simulator though, it didn't show anything. I'm starting to think that this is a simulator bug. Currently, I'm using Xcode 6 beta 6.

Comment: Seeing anything in the console output? Auto layout will sometimes gives you a hint in there.

Comment: No console output from auto layout. Just the same as before.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a collectionView (super simple view hierarchy).  As soon as I add constraints I get a blank VC.  Any luck with this?

Comment: Started a bounty....

Comment: Are there leading/trailing alignment constraints on that scroll view?

Comment: Yes. I want the scroll view to scale to different screen sizes. Just to give a bit of an update, readjusting the constraints got something to show up. In the end, I just approached the issue differently. I just connected some of my constraints to my code and worked with that. But, it doesn't really solve this question.

Comment: @MyronSlaw: Can someone post the link of a Github project that fails to display something on the simulator when Auto layout constraints are supposed to be non ambiguous? I can't reproduce this problem...

Comment: @AdilPatel did you add constrains for scroll view.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, I did add constraints. I added leading, trailing, vertical, and horizontal space constraints.

Comment: Any chance you can add the project here?

Comment: Have you try to open the project using the latest Xcode?

Comment: I solved this by replacing leading and trailing ALIGNMENT  restraints with leading and trailing space constraints. This fixed the problem, but I'm not sure why it happened. I'll look into it and come back in a few hours.

Comment: Also I would look into using size classes for supporting different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the issue by adding a collection view to a standard view controller and this seems to be the problem:

[image: Constraints added when selecting "Add suggest constraints"]

[image]
Having Xcode add suggested constraints gives you this, which causes the view to not show up.

It is aligning the view's left and right to the layout guides (which doesn't seem to be right)

You will have to manually add spacing constraints to your view.

This is what you want:

[image]

Comment: So I guess the issue was that Xcode's suggested constraints isn't as clever as I thought, or I just didn't give a correct set up. In either case, it explains why also I could only resolve the issue by redoing all my constraints without using any suggested ones.

Comment: Yeah unless you are a master of auto layout, it's best to just add the obvious ones and have Xcode add the missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on the assistant editor and use Preview while tweaking your constraints.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [mattknott.com](http://www.mattknott.com/images/screenshot.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but the preview is showing the correct UI to be rendered. What I've noticed is that anything I do on auto layout is broken. I even created a test project with a simple label. When I drag it on, the app runs fine and the iOS sim runs it well. But as soon as I add constraints, even that simple label fails to show in the sim (despite being well-positioned in IB). I'm becoming more and more convinced that this is an Xcode 6 bug as the entire auto layout is broken. When I did something similar in Xcode 5, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do your Editing in   "wAny hAny  For All Layouts Base values"  mode. then you will not see blank screen while testing on different devices.

Mode selection can be one from bottom bar.
Good Luck